# Squeeze theorem help

Tags: calculus, continuity

> ## Problem 2
>
> In Calculus lecture 1, we introduced the "sequence" version of the Sandwiching Theorem.  In fact, we also have a "function" version of the same theorem:  given functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$, if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}h(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=L\in\Bbb R$ and there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $h(x)\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ for any $x$ satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=L$.
>
> If $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^2,& x\in \Bbb Q\\ x^4,& x\notin \Bbb Q\end{array} \right.$, please use the Sandwiching Theorem to show $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=0$.

I need help with the question, would I solve it using the delta and epsilon approach ?

Answer (score 1):

No, that' not necessary. Here's a hint:

If $|x|<1$, then $|x^4|<|x^2|<|x|$.

Comment: the piecewise function confused me so I really dont know how to proceed

Comment: But in all cases, you have $|f(x)|\le|x|$. Isn't it  enough to apply the squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in[-1,1]$, we have $x^4\leq x^2$, and therefore $f(x)\leq x^2$. Furthermore, $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$. More succintly, for $x\in[-1,1]$, $$0\leq f(x)\leq x^2,$$ and therefore, by the Squeeze Theorem, since $$\lim_{x\to0}0=\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0,$$ we can conclude that $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0.$$

Comment: Im still confused how the piecewise function came amd what to do with it

Comment: @Mo Mahmood The only thing that matters about $f$ is that it’s bounded both above and below by functions that tend to zero when $x\to0$. $f$ could be much more complex, but if this condition held, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ would still be zero. Does this answer your doubt?